# InReact and Tailwind, When I used className() library, Object's value to ClassNames() function, what happened?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, postcss

If there is an object liken this

```
const obj = {"key1": 540}
```

And I used key1's value to classNames() computed key like this

```
<div className={classNames("some css properties", { [`w-[${obj.key1}px]`]: true})}>...</div>
```

But, that code is not working.

hmm...please explain what I am misunderstanding.
I think postcss is not parsing properly because I used the wrong way in the process of parsing the className.

Please explain the parsing process or other technical aspects. Even after reading the official documentation, I don't understand it well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```html
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
>
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```html
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

So in this case, Tailwind sees the string literal string `w-[${obj.key1}px]` and does not generate a rule for this, as it would make no sense. It does not run the code and never sees `w-[540px]`.

You could consider using a `style` attribute:

```
<div style={{ width: obj.key1 }}>
```

Or have the full class defined in `obj.key1` (you would also need to make sure that the file this object is declared in is covered by the `content` file globs):

```js
const obj = {"key1": 'w-[540px]'};
```

```
<div className={classNames("some css properties", { [obj.key1]: true})}>
```

Comment: In classnames library's docs, is `Dynamics class name` different in this case?
https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames#dynamic-class-names-with-es2015

Comment: Nope! *Dynamic class names* in `classnames`'s documentation means the same thing here. `classnames` should output the class name in React fine – this is not the issue. As stated in the answer, the issue is that Tailwind needs to see class names as *full unbroken strings* in the source code it scans to generate the appropriate CSS rule.

Comment: I unknowingly equated the className library with Tailwind. What I realized after listening to you and thinking is that className() only changes the className and is independent of how Tailwind works. Thank you very much. @Wongin